# One way car rental between Las Vegas and North Rim Grand Canyon

Tags: transportation, car-rentals, grand-canyon

My family will be visiting the Grand Canyon (North Rim).  My husband and I will fly to Las Vegas and rent a car.  Our daughters will be joining us a few days later.  They will also fly to Las Vegas, but they will only need to rent a car one way, from Vegas to the Grand Canyon as they will travel back with us.  I am not having any luck finding a rental agency for the one way trip.  Any advice?

Comment: What is the relative expense of keeping two cars for the entire trip?

Answer (score 11):

I would venture a guess that dropping a car off at the North Rim will be impossible, since there's virtually nothing there, certainly no rental agencies that I'm aware of -- how would you get there without a car in the first place?

Some alternatives, neither of them cheap:

1. Take a [direct bus](http://www.grandcanyontourcompany.com/busonly.html) from Las Vegas to the South Rim ($99/person, you may find cheaper fares with other companies), connect to the [Rim-to-Rim](http://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/bus.htm#CP_JUMP_192847) shuttle service (4.5 hours one-way, $85/person).
2. Drive or take a bus from Vegas to either [Flagstaff](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Flagstaff) ($23/person on Greyhound) or [Williams](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Williams_%28Arizona%29), then take [the shuttle service](http://www.grandcanyonshuttles.com/) to the North Rim -- but it costs $450 minimum!

Note that both shuttles are seasonal and operate only May to October.

All in all, you'd probably be best off altering your itinerary to meet your daughters at the South Rim, Flagstaff or Williams instead.

Comment: arizonashuttle.com also serves grand canyon canyon from flagstaff, and can possibly connect to their phoenix to flagstaff service(?). the earlier costs 29, the latter 45.

Comment: The OP is coming from Las Vegas.

Comment: that is so, I was trying to point out that your cost estimate is perhaps based on too few providers and thus much higher than actually achievable. but hey they could hitch-hike too, right? :)

Comment: Well, it'd be $23 for Greyhound to Flagstaff, $29 with your shuttle to the South Rim and then $85 to the North Rim -- but I doubt the schedules will let you pull that off in one day, so you have to stay somewhere and it'll probably cost more in the end.